MariaDB, Data::UUID GUID: data too long for column binary(16)
I have a table:
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  id BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

I created a value to insert into the id field:
$sql = 'INSERT INTO sessions (id) VALUES(?)';
my $generator = Data::UUID->new;
my $session_id = $generator->create();
$result = $dbh->do($sql, undef, $session_id);

According to the documentation to Data::UUID module:
# creates binary (16 byte long binary value) UUID.
$ug->create();

https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::UUID
But when I try to INSERT the data I get an error from MariaDB:

Data too long for column 'id'

Why is it too long if the field it 16 bytes long and according to docs the size of $session_id is also 16 bytes?
The issue I suspect is the driver: I connect using "dbi:MariaDB:$dbinst:$dbhost", while another user who tried mysql driver didn't face any errors.

what does select length(?), char_length(?) return given the $session_id?   what version of Data::UUID?

@ysth I tried length to calculate number of bytes, it gives 16.

in perl?  I meant in sql, to see what it is actually sending to the server

MariaDB >= 10.7
You're better off using the UUID type in MariaDB, and using Data::UUID::create_str. That would look something like this:
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  id UUID NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

$sql = 'INSERT INTO sessions (id) VALUES(?)';
my $generator = Data::UUID->new;
my $session_id = $generator->create_str();
$result = $dbh->do($sql, undef, $session_id);

MariaDB < 10.7
The simplest solution is just to use varchar(16), preferably with the MyRocks engine if it is available (MyRocks will drastically improve varchar key performance and compression):
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  id VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=MyRocks;

$sql = 'INSERT INTO sessions (id) VALUES(?)';
my $generator = Data::UUID->new;
my $session_id = $generator->create_bin();
$result = $dbh->do($sql, undef, $session_id);

Explanation
For some reason, Data::UUID returns a value with a length(?) varied from 23 to 27 bytes, but a char_length(?) of 16. This is probably a bug with either Data::UUID or DBD::MariaDB/DBD::mysql.

My MariaDB is 10.5.13: too old for this data type.

@user4035 You could use varchar(36) instead

@user4035 You could also consider upgrading to the latest LTS (11.4) as 10.5 is deprecated in July 2025

BINARY(36) would avoid any character set conversion and its always a fixed length as an alternate for < 10.11 versions. If uuidv1 acceptable there's also the sql uuid function. MariaDB also has had almost 3 years of bug fixes since 10.5.13 too.

@RawleyFowler "You could use varchar(36)" - This is what I did. Generated a string and saved it into varchar(36), even though it consumes more space.

@RawleyFowler "You could also consider upgrading to the latest LTS (11.4) as 10.5 is deprecated in July 2025" - Slackware stable is very conservative. It's latest package is "mariadb-10.5.26", upgraded on Fri Aug 9 21:22:03 UTC 2024. Have to wait for another year.

Do you have any ideas why binary(16) could lead to an error? I checked the length of the generated binary data, it's exactly 16 bytes. Removed "use utf-8".

@RawleyFowler Did you try to insert the 16 bytes into your new MariaDB in Perl? Does it work?

@user4035 The size of the variable is pretty negligible. For instance we use varchar(36) (on an old MariaDB instance) in a table of close to 300 million records. This table has massive throughput, we achieved good performance using the MyRocks engine. I've also updated the answer with a solution that works with the binary type.
